# How to integrate 2 projects into one .WAR, Deploy and Maintain them independently?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

I have a scenario specific to tomcat deployment. I have 2 applications

```
/Webapps
        /Application-1  
        /Application-2
```

Here:

1. I want create a single .WAR file to deploy both application and access them independently
2. When Application-1 is alive, bring down only Application-2 for maintenance
3. When Application-2 is ready, deploy using single .WAR created (where it contains 2 applications), however, it should not impact Application-1

This is the challenge thrown at me and I am trying out ways with no solution yet. Appreciate any help to achieve these 3 steps, please.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Based on your requirements, the answer would seem to be create two WAR files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is a way to update your war in the server without having to tear it down, there is a way to do it with tomcat 7 parallel deployment http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment

> You may deploy multiple versions of a web application with the same
>   context path at the same time. The rules used to match requests to a
>   context version are as follows:
>
> If no session information is present in the request, use the latest
>   version. If session information is present in the request, check the
>   session manager of each version for a matching session and if one is
>   found, use that version. If session information is present in the
>   request but no matching session can be found, use the latest version.

If that is not what you are looking for, please, update your question with a better explanation.